# Apache Rewriterule change

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want specific pages without an extension to direct to their php counterpart. Right now, I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(login|logout)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(login|logout)\?(.*)$ $1.php?$2
```

Is there a way to do this in one rule? Should I do this in one rule?

Answer (score 0):

This will generalize it for just about any possible filename. Tweak the pattern match if you need to. ([Thank you to the Internet for this example.](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/))

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Or you can enable `Options +MultiViews` but this may carry a performance penalty, since while it works it's not what MultiViews was designed for.

Comment: This doesn't appear to do what I want. Doesn't this change foo.php?bar into bar.php?

Comment: No, it changes `/foo?bar` into `/foo.php?bar` if `/foo.php` is a file that exists on the filesystem.

Comment: My bad, the initial / threw me. I still don't understand this though.